# Nested 'any' and 'all' condition in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lists

`list1 = [['a','b','c'],['m','n','o'],['x','y','z']]`

Now, I want to check if *all elements of any one of these* 'sub-lists' are present in an incoming list called `list2`.

For example, if

```
list2 = ['a','c','e','b'] #Code would return True as a,b,c all from list1[0] match
list2 = ['a','c','m','x','e'] # False as all elements from any one sub-list do not match
list2 = ['g','h','i','x','y','z'] # True as all elements from list1[2] matched
```

I know that this can be done using a nested `all` within `any` python function. If `list1` was not a nested list, I would have used

```
result = any(elem in list2 for elem in list1) # To check for any one
```

or

```
result = all(elem in list2 for elem in list1) # To check for all
```

However, I am at loss to do a nested any/all type of list comprehension. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If your list elements are hashable, then `any(set(x) <= set(list2) for x in list1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a combination of `any` and `all`:

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['m','n','o'],['x','y','z']]

def test(l1, l2):
    return any(all(x in l2 for x in sub) for sub in l1)

print(test(list1, ['a','c','e','b']))
print(test(list1, ['a','c','m','x','e']))
print(test(list1, ['g','h','i','x','y','z']))
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```

The test means: if `all` `x`'s of `any` of the `sub`lists are in `list2`.

Comment: I have a feeling that converting to sets and using `difference` might allow to skip one level of depth in the comprehension, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ChatterOne You're right, check @Jab's answer below for the `set` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Why not make `list2` a set and use `set.issuperset` to see if all elements are in `list2`

```
list2 = {'g','h','i','x','y','z'}
print(any(list2.issuperset(elem) for elem in list1))
#True
```

You can even make this more simple using map although the comprehension is more readable

```
any(map(list2.issuperset, list1))
```

If you go this route I suggest not using `list2` as the name to avoid confusion

Comment: These are very interesting suggestions. I am sort of naive at Python but will certainly give these a try. And you are right about using names like "list1", "list2". Will avoid those when writing the code. Thanks!